# navigator.mimeTypes structure

Tags: javascript

I'm curious about how it is working this structure. When I'm accesing the navigator.mimetypes from Javascript I'm accesing an object.

```
>>> typeof(navigator.mimeTypes)
"object"
```

That object has list of objects.

navigator.mimeTypes[Object_0, Object_1, Object_2, ...]

```
>>> typeof(navigator.mimeTypes[0])
"object"
```

For example, I can retrieve the first object:

> > > navigator.mimeTypes[0]

```
MimeType { constructor=MimeType, enabledPlugin=Plugin, type="application/x-vnd.google.update3webcontrol.3"}
```

Can anyone explain me why this is working?

```
>>> navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"]

MimeType { constructor=MimeType, type="application/x-shockwave-flash", description="",more...}
```

I mean why I am able to find the specified object by means of ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] ??

javascript will be a new world to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`navigator.mimeTypes` returns an object called `MimeTypeArray` it's not a traditional JavaScript array but an object that had Array like properties, you can access it's properties either by index or name.

edit: When you use `navigator.mimeTypes['someType']` you're treating the `MimeTypeArray` like a hash map, that has `someType` mapped to a `MimeType` object in the array that also has a `type` property of the same value as the key. This is a strange object in the DOM (not technically JavaScript) and you don't typically see many objects like this.

Comment: Why am i accessing directly to the "type" property of that object? Do you know how to create it? If I see a small example of how it is created I could understand it better (hope so). Btw, Thanks anyway for the explanation

Comment: You're not really... when you use `navigator.mimeTypes['someType']` you're treating the MimeTypeArray like a hash map, that has `'someType'` mapped to a `MimeType` object in the array that also has a `type` property of the same value. This is a strange object in the DOM (not technically JavaScript) and you don't typically see many objects like this. I'm not sure how to implement an object like that and I think it uses a little bit of behind the scenes magic to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetMimeTypes() {
    var message = "";
    // Internet Explorer supports the mimeTypes collection, but it is always empty
    if (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes.length > 0) {
        var mimes = navigator.mimeTypes;
        for (var i=0; i < mimes.length; i++) {
            message += "<b>" + mimes[i].type + "</b> : " + mimes[i].description + "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        message = "Your browser does not support this example!";
    }
    var info = document.getElementById ("login_info");
    info.innerHTML = message;
}
GetMimeTypes();
```