# How to create a new instance of MimeType in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a custom MimeType object. How do I know what parameters I should pass to constructor?

```
new MimeType({"description": "test", "type": "application/test"})
TypeError: Illegal constructor.
```

Comment: There is no doc on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/mimeTypes) for this. seem that you can't create your own MimeType objects.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create new MimeType objects via JavaScript, only interrogate existing ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934287/navigator-mimetypes-structure